# How does cocoa's obsolete CGSCStringValue function actually work?

Tags: string, function, core-graphics

I've been using **CGSPrivate.h** for cocoa development under MacOSX for a while. I'm now using it under Lion (10.7.x), and it turns out that the **CGSCStringValue()** function described in that file no longer exists under that OS version.

I want to make use of the functionality of **CGSCStringValue()** -- *i.e.*, converting a *CGSValue* to its associated *char** when appropriate -- and I'm wondering if anyone knows how that function is actually implemented.

I've tried various forms of casting of the *CGSValue*, but to no avail. So could anyone point me to some documentation or actual cocoa code that runs in 10.7 which will take a *CGSValue* that's associated with a string as input and return its *char** equivalent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented by checking the type (to make sure it's really a `CFString`) and calling `CFStringGetCString()`. You can do that yourself, there is no real need for `CGSCStringValue`.